# Deploying with maven to weblogic 11g

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a maven web project that has some web services, EJBs that interact with the database using JPA. This was a previous JDeveloper project I changed the structure to Maven, and started using eclipse.

The issue is when I deploy it creates a WAR file with all the files, including EJBs, etc and from what I have seen [this is not possible](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ears_wars_and_size_matters).

When Jdeveloper was deploying this project, it was creating an EAR file and put all the EJBS in an EJB.jar and the war file with all the POJO's.

Is there any way of doing this with maven ? Is there a simple solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using maven, a clean approach should be to reformat your project as a multi-module project with an ejb project(containing EJB and JPA), a war project depending on the ejb (containing POJO classes) and an ear project containing the ejb and war modules. Read about maven-ejb-plugin, maven-war-plugin and maven-ear-plugin.